# For $D$ is a P.I.D. , $R=D/(d)$ is semisimple if and only if $d$ is the product of distinct non-associate irreducible elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $D$ be a principal ideal domain with $d$ a nonzero nonunit element and $R=D/(d)$.

how to show that:

> $R$ is semisimple if and only if $d$ is the product of distinct non-associate irreducible elements.

Since $D$ is a P.I.D. ,$R$ is both Artinian and Noetherian, hence $R$ is semisimple if and only if the Jacobson radical $J(R)=0$, and I getting stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\implies$ (by contraposition)  Suppose we factor $d=\prod p_i^{e_i}$ into powers of nonassociate irreducibles. If for some $j$ it happens that $e_j>1$, then $\frac{ d}{ p_j}\neq 0$ in the quotient ring, and $(\frac {d} {p_j} )^2=0$. Thus the ring would have a nonzero nilpotent element and would not be semisimple.

$\impliedby$ Now suppose $d=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$, a finite product of nonassociate irreducibles.

Then the set of ideals $\{(p_i)\mid i=1\ldots n\}$ are a coprime family of maximal ideals, so the Chinese Remainder theorem for commutative rings says that $\cap_{i=1}^n(p_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n (p_i)=(d)$ and that $R/(d)\cong \prod_{i=1}^nR/(p_i)$. The right hand side is a finite product of fields, so $R/(d)$ is semisimple.

Comment: what  the $\frac d e$ refers to in the first paragraph?

Comment: @Mao Sorry, it was an egregious typo.